# Do I need an S3 bucket for Python ETL scripts that run as AWS Batch jobs for a Splunk Forwarder?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-batch

I am trying to deploy (in CDK) scheduled Python ETL scripts as Batch jobs (Fargate?) to parse data from AWS and other tools we utilize. A Spunk Forwarder consumes this data and sends it to our Splunk Index. Am I going to need an S3 bucket for the output of logs from my ETL scripts? How can I deploy the Splunk Forwarder alongside these scripts?

There are about 5-6 scripts that I would like to deploy via CDK.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Batch jobs can send STDERR and STDOUT to CloudWatch Logs. Depends on how logging is configured in your Python scripts, that may be the easy answer. If logging is configured to write to a file, then yes I would recommend you upload the file to S3 after the ETL is finished.

Output from the scripts (the ETL results) will need to land someplace, and S3 is a great choice for that. Your Splunk Forwarder can be set up to monitor the bucket for new data and ingest. If the scripts directly send data to the forwarder you should not need a S3 bucket, but I personally would recommend that you decouple the ETL data from ingestion of the result into Splunk.

Splunk Forwarders (stable servers) would be deployed separate from AWS Batch resources.